# A problem on geometry of regualr n-gonal cupolae.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider a cupola (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupola_(geometry)) of degree 6 or above (you can't have an equilateral triangle as a face). What should be breadth of rectangular faces so that both top and botton bases become regular polygons of same side length?
I do have a feeling that it is proportional to number of sides as top angle of isosceles triangles looks to decrease as number of sides increase but I am not sure about that.

Comment: I don't understand this question: you can place top and bottom polygons as you like, provided their centers lie on the same line perpendicular to both polygons, and then join their vertices to form lateral faces.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But choosing any breadth (other than the specific one, which I had asked for in the question)for rectangles will make the botton polygon not regular, but a polygon with alternating side lengths.

Comment: I don't understand why: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, only a figure showing what I wrote in a comment to the question. Both top and bottom are regular polygons with the same side length.

[image]

Comment: Oops. My bad. I did not consider that the angle of inclination of lateral faces can change. Thank you for helping me. Btw how did you make that animation?

Comment: @AryanAnand I made it with GeoGebra Classic.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for bothering you.